# ServiceStack.Text RegisterLicense throws exception

Tags: c#, servicestack

I just recently upgraded to ServiceStack.Text 4.x, the paid license. One of my apps is a console app and it uses the following code to register the license:

```
public static class License
{
    public static void ServiceStackInit()
    {
        //1x Indie Developer(Text)
        //Certificate:  {removed}
        //Licensed to:  {removed}
        //Quantity: 1 Developer
        //Valid Until:  April 10, 2017
        try
        {
            ServiceStack.Licensing.RegisterLicense(@"3694..");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Registering ServiceStack.Text license failed: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

The result is an exception thrown by the method *RegisterLicense*.

```
Initialization failed: The type initializer for 'ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer' threw an exception.. 
Inner: The type initializer for 'ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig' threw an exception.
```

I believe my license key is fine and I also believe that it was running before.

Any ideas why I am running into a problem now?

Comment: Are you registering your license key immediately on App Startup? Also what platform and .NET fx version are you running this on?

Comment: Well, it's a console app. The call to *init()* is almost the first thing within *Main()*. And within *init()* the call to *ServiceStackInit()* (see above) is almost the first call. Why? Does it matter? .net 4.6.1, Win 2012R2

Comment: If you meant: are you sure that *ServiceStackInit()* will be called before any ServiceStack method is called ... yes, I think so. At least my program does not call any ServiceStack functionality before I call the *ServiceStackInit()* .. no idea if there is any locking startup code or alike in the library. In addition, I also put the key into the environment variable SERVICESTACK_LICENSE. Just to be extra sure, I restarted the machine between 2 debugging sessions - still the same.

Comment: Can you try running `JsConfig.InitStatics();` before you run any ServiceStack code, if that doesn't resolve the issue can you email a small, stand-alone repro of the issue to team@servicestack.net (inc license key) and we'll resolve it from there.